# Jsoup on specific table data

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-table

First of all, I'm sorry of the erotic content of the page but look past it , it's not about the page itself.

I'm trying to get the price of something from this page: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E5LFH/)

On row 67 it says "Adviesprijs:", I need the value in the next `td` after that, without the  btw stuff (which is Belgian tax if you're wondering)

For example: "19.95" as a String

How do I get this content using JSoup?

This is what I have so far :

```
Element element = doc.getElementById("productdetails");

if (element.text().contains("Adviesprijs:")) { 
   String price = element.parent().ownText(); 
   System.out.println(price); 
}
```

It doesn't work though.

Comment: You'll find a good overview here - http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Comment: @Adel I've looked over the entire jsoup site but I can't really narrow it down to what I want , this is what I have so far : 

Element element = doc.getElementById("productdetails");

            if (element.text().contains("Adviesprijs:")) {
                String price = element.parent().ownText();
                System.out.println(price);
            }

It doesn't work though :(

Answer (score 0):

you better use a [selector](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for this:

```
/* select all tags with "Adviesprijs:" text */
Elements result = doc.select("*:containsOwn(Adviesprijs:)");

/* iterate over all elements found */
for( Element e : result )
{
    String key = e.text(); /* "Adviesprijs:" */
    String value = e.nextElementSibling().text(); /* text of next element */

    System.out.println(key + "\t" + value);
}
```

prints: `Adviesprijs:   € 19,95 (incl. 21% btw)`

Comment: As amazing as the code looked, it doesn't seem to do anything at all, it doesn't find anything , even if I put System.out.println("test"); at the beginning of the iteration it doesn't do it

If you're wondering how the rest of my code looks : http://pastebin.com/TeEHFbuR

Comment: I saved your html into a file and parsed it with `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(f, null);` (`f` is the file). This works fine and the values are printed as above. Please test if the url you use at `connect` method is ok and check the document you get. Is your code for pc or android?

Comment: PC, and it doesn't return anything, not quite sure why.

Comment: Can you test your code in a single class? So you have only the jsoup part and ensure there's no trouble with another code parts. "*doesn't return anything*", do you mean even no document (or only an empty one)?